# Android Auto: What means - application asks for an update which prevents testing of functionality in the Android Auto environment

Tags: java, google-play, android-auto

I'm working on `android auto` (**not for** Android Automotive OS). The app runs on `DHU` but publishing in Google Play was rejected:

Reason: application asks for an update which prevents testing of functionality in the Android Auto environment.

Don't know what that means.
Does anyone know what's to do?

Thanks,
Alejandro

Comment: Sounds like a good question to ask on the [official github repository of android auto](https://github.com/google/android-auto-companion-android).

Comment: recommended site is for Android Automotive OS, not for Android Auto for cars